# Xcode 3.2.5 on OSX El Capitan 10.11.5

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan

When trying to install Xcode 3.2.5. on OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 it fails with the error message:

An unknown installation error occurred. The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

I tried to install it using the GUI installer and using the command line:

cd /Applications
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/Xcode\ and\ iOS\ SDK/Xcode\ and\ iOS\ SDK.mpkg -target / -allowUntrusted -verbose -lang en

Both fail...

So what can I do to be able to install this old Xcode version?

Comment: Why do you want to install an Xcode so old?

Comment: Well, to be able to build plugins for Adobe InDesign CS6... or I have to downgrade to a previous MacOS...

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I'd install an older MacOS in a vagrant box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following option

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

And uninstall new version of Xcode if any installed on OSX